# What is the most efficient std container for non-duplicated items?

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, set, containers

What is the most efficient way of adding non-repeated elements into STL container and what kind of container is the fastest? I have a large amount of data and I'm afraid each time I try to check if it is a new element or not, it takes a lot of time. I hope map be very fast.

```
// 1- Map
map<int, int> Map;
...
if(Map.find(Element)!=Map.end()) Map[Element]=ID;

// 2-Vector
vector<int> Vec;
...
if(find(Vec.begin(), Vec.end(), Element)!=Vec.end()) Vec.push_back(Element);

// 3-Set
// Edit: I made a mistake: set::find is O(LogN) not O(N)
```

Comment: "*I read that find in set is very slow O(N) versus O(logN)*" If you're referring to `std::set<>`, then no, that's incorrect.

Comment: If you don't need the key-value semantics of the map, `std::set` doesn't insert duplicates and is typically implemented as a red-black tree ([ref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)).

Comment: `std::set` is often implemented using `std::map`.  Why don't you benchmark?

Comment: The reference about slowness of sets : http://www.lafstern.org/matt/col1.pdf

Comment: @Hesam, From the link, *std::find performs a
linear search, so the time it takes is proportional to N (where N is the number of elements you're looking through),
while the time taken by set::find is proportional to log N*

Comment: You haven't read that very well; it just advises not to use `std::find`.

Comment: @Hesam : That paper says that using the `std::find()` algorithm over a `std::set<>` is O(N), which is correct – but you shouldn't be using `std::find()` over a `std::set<>` in the first place, you should be using `std::set<>::find()`, so it's a moot point.

Comment: I confused std::find with set::find and according to title jump into wrong conclusion

Comment: std::set uses operator< for sorting. Using it with Ogre::Vector3 does not work at all.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Both `set` and `map` has `O(log(N))` performance for looking up keys. `vector` has `O(N)`.

The difference between `set` and `map`, as far as you should be concerned, is whether you need to associate a key with a value, or just store a value directly. If you need the former, use a `map`, if you need the latter, use a `set`.

In both cases, you should just use `insert()` instead of doing a `find()`.

The reason is `insert()` will insert the value into the container if and only if the container does not already contain that value (in the case of `map`, if the container does not contain that key). This might look like

```
Map.insert(std::make_pair(Element, ID));
```

for a map or

```
Set.insert(Element);
```

for a set.

You can consult the return value to determine whether or not an insertion was actually performed.

---

If you're using C++11, you have two more choices, which are `std::unordered_map` and `std::unordered_set`. These both have amortized `O(1)` performance for insertions and lookups. However, they also require that the key (or value, in the case of set) be hashable, which means you'll need to specialize `std::hash<>` for your key. Conversely, `std::map` and `std::set` require that your key (or value, in the case of set) respond to `operator<()`.

Answer (score 7):

If you're using C++11, you can use `std::unordered_set`. That would allow you `O(1)` existence-checking (technically amortized `O(1)` -- `O(n)` in the worst case).

`std::set` would probably be your second choice with `O(lg n)`.

Basically, `std::unordered_set` is a hash table and `std::set` is a tree structure (a red black tree in every implementation I've ever seen)<sup>1</sup>.

Depending on how well your hashes distribute and how many items you have, a std::set might actually be faster. If it's truly performance critical, then as always, you'll want to do benchmarking.

<sup>1) Technically speaking, I don't believe either are required to be implemented as a hash table or as a balanced BST. If I remember correctly, the standard just mandates the run time bounds, not the implementation -- it just turns out that those are the only viable implementations that fit the bounds.</sup>

Comment: There are a lot of issues with using a hash map though, such as the size of your objects and the security of the hash. They are good, but they aren't the one and only solution to every problem.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain Yes, I noted that (though implicitly). Also, the hashing algorithm used for hash maps have nothing to do with security.  While collisions are still seen as bad, there are different categories of hash functions. A hash table hash needs to be extremely fast, which tends to never coincide with secure. Also, can you expand on the size comment? I'm not sure I understand that one. There will be extra value_type instances, but the keys have to be stored in a hash map the same way that they're stored in a set.

Comment: Security - If a known hash has a known pattern in its collisions and an attacker can encourage your hash map to store them, the buckets will become very large and could cause your program to become super unresponsive. In a server program, for example, this is a security problem and one that Java has suffered (many times?)

Comment: Size - if your objects are huge and you are only storing a few of them, then hashing the objects - an `O(m)` runtime in the size of the object - becomes rather significant and you could benefit from using a `std::set` which may be able to get away with only comparing part of an object.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain Ah, true on both points. As you said, a less-than comparison can short circuit whereas a hashing operation cannot. Typically the hashing is only done on a relatively small part of an object though (and often fixed in size). As for purposely causing collisions and making huge buckets (and thus long linear time operations), that would be quite an interesting security hole. While very feasible, it seems like that would be pretty rare in the wild. I suppose 'rare' still exists though :).

Comment: Unfortunately, it took down several servers based on Java's default hash functions with strings like `a`, `aa`, `aaa` etc. I'll try to turf up some references tomorrow (UK time).

Comment: You also lose cache coherence over a sorted vector and/or well designed trees. Again, I'll see if I can find a reference.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain `a`, `aa`, `aaa`, etc used to hash to the same thing?! That's just terrible design. Hopefully collisions wouldn't be *that* trivial to find even for a non-security aimed hashing function. As for cache coherence, what it all really comes down to is the OP needs to benchmark. We could consider details all day on performance, but benchmarking is the only way to truly know (well, without getting waayyy carried away with code analysis).

Answer (score 3):

You should use a `std::set`; it is a container designed to hold a single (equivalent) copy of an object and is implemented as a binary search tree. Therefore, it is `O(log N)`, not `O(N)`, in the size of the container.

`std::set` and `std::map` often share a large part of their underlying implementation; you should check out your local STL implementation.

Having said all this, complexity is only one measure of performance. You may have better performance using a sorted vector, as it keeps the data local to one another and, therefore, more likely to hit the caches. Cache coherence is a large part of data structure design these days.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to use a `std::set`. It's elements are unique, so you don't need to care about uniqueness when adding elements, and `a.find(k)` (where `a` is an `std::set` and `k` is a value) is defined as being logarithmic in complexity.

Answer (score 1):

if your elements can be hashed for O(1), then better to use an index in a `unordered_map` or `unordered_set` (not in a `map`/`set` because they use RB tree in implementation which is O(logN) find complexity)

Answer (score 1):

Your examples show a definite pattern:

```
check if the value is already in container
  if not, add the value to the container.
```

Both of these operation would potentially take some time. First, looking up an element can be done in O(N) time (linear search) if the elements are not arranged in any particular manner (e.g., just a plain `std::vector`), it could be done in O(logN) time (binary search) if the elements are sorted (e.g., either `std::map` or `std::set`), and it could be done in O(1) time if the elements are hashed (e.g., either `std::unordered_map` or `std::unordered_set`).

The insertion will be O(1) (amortized) for a plain vector or an unordered container (hash container), although the hash container will be a bit slower. For a sorted container like set or map, you'll have log-time insertions because it needs to look for the place to insert it before inserting it.

So, the conclusion, use `std::unordered_set` or `std::unordered_map` (if you need the key-value feature). And you don't need to check before doing the insertion, these are unique-key containers, they don't allow duplicates.

If `std::unordered_set` / `std::unordered_map` (from C++11) or `std::tr1::unordered_set` / `std::tr1::unordered_map` (since 2007) are not available to you (or any equivalent), then the next best alternative is `std::set` / `std::map`.